# HAProxy Path Matching

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to forward all request to frontend with url `/api/*` to a specific backend. I used the following:

```
frontend fr
# Other relevant settings
acl is_controller_req path_sub -i controller
acl is_controller_api path -i -m beg /api

use_backend controller_service if is_controller_req
use_backend controller_service if is_controller_api
```

The first acl works for all routes under the domain `http://localhost:4200/<PATH>` where each `<PATH>` has the controller keyword in them. For the second one, I get `503 Service Unavailable`. How do I match these paths and setup my `acl` accordingly?

Comment: Your example code uses the `controller_service` backend for both acls. No wonder it forwards to that one...

Comment: @bblue Well that is the expected behavior. The backend for api and all other routes are under the same domain and server

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match paths that begin with `/api/`, you can try using the [path_beg](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#7.3.6-path) sample:

```
acl is_controller_api path_beg /api/
```

Comment: Tried this; still getting 503 Service Unavailable. The acl doesn't evaluate to true and use the controller_service backend

Comment: it should be the accepted answer. It works for me the first time.